# move_base navigating robot to close to costmap?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, jackal, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm experiencing an issue where anytime move_base sets a trajectory for the robot to follow, it inevitably falls too close to an obstacle and ends up scraping against it, or gets stuck in an escape loop where it keeps backing out in order to avoid the obstacle but repeats the same trajectory instead of re-planning. How can I discourage this behaviour?

```
move_base settings:
    TrajectoryPlannerROS:    
      acc_lim_x: 2.0
      acc_lim_theta:  1.0
    
      max_vel_x: 0.18
      min_vel_x: 0.05
    
      max_vel_theta: 1.57
      min_vel_theta: -1.57
      min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.314
    
      holonomic_robot: false
      escape_vel: -0.20

      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.35
      latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

      sim_time: 4.0
      sim_granularity: 0.02
      angular_sim_granularity: 0.03
      vx_samples: 30
      vtheta_samples: 30
      controller_frequency: 20.0
    
      meter_scoring: true
      occdist_scale:  0.1
      pdist_scale: 0.4
      gdist_scale: 0.6    
      heading_lookahead: 1.0
      heading_scoring: false
      heading_scoring_timestep: 1.8
      dwa: true
      simple_attractor: false
      publish_cost_grid_pc: true
    
      oscillation_reset_dist: 0.4
      escape_reset_dist: 0.0
      escape_reset_theta: 0.4

    map_type: costmap
    origin_z: 0.0
    z_resolution: 1
    z_voxels: 2
    
    obstacle_range: 5.5 #2.5
    raytrace_range: 3.0
    
    publish_voxel_map: false
    transform_tolerance: 0.5
    meter_scoring: false
    
    footprint: [[-0.21, -0.165], [-0.21, 0.165], [0.21, 0.165], [0.21, -0.165]]
    footprint_padding: 0.045
    
    plugins:
    - {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    
    obstacles_layer:
      observation_sources: scan
      scan: {sensor_frame: front_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: -2.0, max_obstacle_height: 2.0, obstacle_range: 2.5, raytrace_range: 3.0}
    
    inflater_layer:
     inflation_radius: 0.06
    shutdown_costmaps: false
    
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    controller_patience: 5.0
    
    planner_frequency: 20.0
    planner_patience: 5.0
    
    oscillation_timeout: 0.0
    oscillation_distance: 0.5
    
    recovery_behavior_enabled: true
    clearing_rotation_allowed: true
    global_costmap:
       global_frame: map
       robot_base_frame: base_link
       update_frequency: 10.0
       publish_frequency: 5.0
       width: 40.0
       height: 40.0
       resolution: 0.02
       origin_x:  0.0
       origin_y:  0.0
       static_map: true
       rolling_window: false
    
       plugins:
       - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
       - {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
       - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    local_costmap:
       global_frame: map
       robot_base_frame: base_link
       update_frequency: 10.0
       publish_frequency: 5.0
       width: 10.0
       height: 10.0
       resolution: 0.02
       static_map: false
       rolling_window: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300890/move_base-navigating-robot-to-close-to-costmap?/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-18**:
I'm by no means a navigation expert, but you have made sure your `footprint` setting is correct? `footprint_padding` is set to 4.5cm, that is not very much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your inflation_radius under the inflater_layer is too low. Ideally you should set this parameter to half the size of your robot (0.21 in your case). This is the radius in meters to which the map inflates obstacle cost values.  This should make the global planner plan the path further away from the obstacles. 
In addition, if you want to disable the recovery behavior, you should set the `clearing_rotation_allowed` parameter in move_base to false.

```
<param name="/clearing_rotation_allowed" value="false" />
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Increase your [inflation_radius](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Inflation) to be greater than the radius of your robot.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2